# Determining what to unit test and what not to

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd

I am still getting to understand Test Driven Development.  I have the following requirements for a user registration module of an application.

1. The system must capture the user's firstname, lastname, email address and optionally, postal address
2. The firstname and lastname must be alphabetical
3. The firstname and lastname may not be empty
4. The email address must be a valid address and is mandatory
5. The postal address is optional.

To implement the above in java. I have written the following code:

1. The java bean containing the above fields and having corresponding getters and setters
2. Validation annotation for the above fields
3. A dao for saving a user
4. A user interface for entering the user details.

Question: Which of the above code should be covered with unit tests? i.e The bean's getter and setters, the presence of validation annotations, the ability of the dao to save the user, the presence of the relevant form elements in the UI.

Comment: please tag this with the appropriate technology (e.g Java).

Comment: @RPM1984: Why? The question is clearly about unit testing and TDD, and answers would apply equally well to any other language.

Comment: @Platinum Azure - in terms of "should i/shouldnt i", i would agree. But the actual implementation would differ greatly from technology for technology (UI testing for instance). But i guess this isn't about the how, so i retract my statement.

Comment: So, John O'Hara is going to have a hard time registering, as is Ms Sarah Wickham-Brown.  (Plus we had an employee from the India sub-continent whose name was Gaurav; no last name - or was it no first name.)  And 'The system must capture the ... postal address' and 'The postal address is optional' are quasi-contradictory.

Comment: @Platinum, @RPM1984: since the question mentions Java (beans, DAO) etc, I'm not sure how much the language specific label matters.

Comment: If you have already written the code then by definition you are not doing TDD. You can (and should) offcourse unit-test what you have written to death.

Comment: @Lieven, What answer would you give if i had not indicated that i have written the code. Those are the requirements, what tests should i be writing now? Thats the answer am looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I write tests for things that I reason "can I've done this wrong?". That means I don't bother to test libraries others supplied - only my configurations of them.

Getters and setters - most definitely not. I use Eclipse to generate them, it's not worth testing.

The annotations for validation - I wouldn't test that they, for instance, correctly implement a null check, I rely on that they do what it says on the tin, but I would test the presence of them. Do the right field have them? And if I configured them with a regexp, I would test I got the regexp right.

Another example, if I store my POJO with Hibernate. I don't check that `Session.save(myObj)` is working, but the stuff I can have done wrong such as transaction boundaries and mapping configuration (are all fields saved) etc.

I find user interface testing really hard. I've many times thought "this time I will" - but anything more complex than a form, and I give up. Using a pattern like MVP means I can inject events to test most of the computational stuff - but there's still the connection to the UI which isn't tested. I usually end up with testing bits of it, complex data handling, things that feel error prone.

Answer (score 2):

For one thing I know about TDD, you never ever write the code first.

You first write a test, as your test fails, you write/generate code to fix it and then write more tests to break the functionality which you intend to achieve and write/fix the original code for it.

Its best if you have 100% code coverage.

Refer to wikipedia for how you need to start with your project with TDD - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development

Comment: Are you suggesting that i write tests for all the sections as specified in the question? including getters and setters? if not, my questions was what should i and what should i not unit test.

Comment: I would add that you should only test code that you yourself write (or are going to write, as TDD suggests you do). Don't try to test (for example) third-party data access libraries, because that's not your job.

Comment: @Sairam, the theory on wikipedia is interesting. but i have a real life situation at hand. Thats why i made the question very specific.

Comment: 'Which of the above code should be covered with unit tests? ' - As Azure says, you need to write tests for all code that you write

Comment: @Stephen C - 'real time' usage was bad . fixed it.

Comment: If you practice TDD, your coverage is 100%